# DB2 - how to find count multiple occurrences of column value

Tags: sql, db2

Im new to DB2 , and tried based on some similar posts, I have a table where I need to find the count of IDs based on where status=P and 
 the count of(primary=1) more than once.
so my result should be 2 here - (9876,3456)
Tried:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(isprimary) Counts
  FROM table 
 GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(isprimary)=1;
```

[image]

Comment: Your image includes no data

Comment: Updated the image

Answer (score 2):

Try the query below:

```
select ID as IDs,Count(isPrimary) as isPrimary
From Table
where Status = 'p' 
Group by ID
Having Count(isPrimary) >1
```

Answer (score 2):

You are close, I think all you need to do is to add a where clause like:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) as Counted
FROM table 
WHERE PrimaryFlag = 1 
  AND[status] = 'P'
GROUP BY id
```

EDIT: if you need to count only the distinct IDs, then try:

```
SELECT COUNT(t.ID) FROM
(
    SELECT id, COUNT(*) as Counted
    FROM table 
    WHERE PrimaryFlag = 1 
      AND[status] = 'P'
    GROUP BY id
) as t
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Ideally- isprimary flag =1 should be only once per ID, but now due to some corrupted data- we have multiple times. Now I need to find IDs where it occurred more than once.

Comment: @RadhaJogendra If you correct the data and add the latest version to your question, I could help for that one as well.

Comment: I meant.. in our tables.. we have such corrupted data and we are trying to find it..